# How to run and debug an android Admin app

Tags: android, kotlin, adb

I'm creating a Kiosk style application which requires a few Admin privileges (such as fullscreen without system ui and screen management to turn off/on the screen), this app is ment for dedicated devices.

Is there any way to set some sort of debug admin app instead so I can simply rebuild and run from Studio instead of the whole manual un-register, build, run, re-register, re-run process?

I've looked into MDM and those things but I don't want to be stuck with an external remote party which requires monthly or yearly fees for simply managing a device.

Used adb to set my app as Admin app, which prohibits any further communication with my IDE.